# Java Selenium driver.close() on iPhone Safari does not work

Tags: java, ios, iphone, selenium, safari

I'm a beginner in selenium automation and I'm trying perform automation tests of our website on iPhone Safari.

These tests should involve browser actions such as clicking an element and then closing the new opened Safari tab.

I managed to perform a click on the element and the new tab was opened successfully, the problem is that for some reason, closing the new tab with driver.close() is not working (no errors been thrown). The above was performed successfully on Desktop browsers such as Chrome and Firefox and on Galaxy Chrome.

The attached code was executed via BrowserStack.
At first, I suspected that the problem was on their side,  but after a short communication with them we've found that the problem happens when running selenium automation on a local iPhone device as well and regardless to BrowserStack.

Can anyone assist me ?

Thanks!

```html
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("browserName", "iPhone");
            caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone XS");
            caps.setCapability("realMobile", "true");
            caps.setCapability("os_version", "14");
            caps.setCapability("name", "iphone");

            caps.setCapability("browserstack.safari.enablePopups", "true");
            caps.setCapability("browserstack.safari.allowAllCookies", "true");
            caps.setCapability("nativeWebTap", true);

            WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);

            driver.get("https://m.imdb.com/");
            
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("original window URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            String originalWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@title='Facebook']")).click();
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
            for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                if(!originalWindow.contentEquals(windowHandle)) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("new window URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            
            driver.close();
            
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("after close window URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            driver.quit();
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium

Thanks for your reply, I've added my code to my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try to switch native context and close the tab: https://gist.github.com/arvind1998/2249362084d9e67cdff265898a2ab2b7